# Installing PyroCMS error when installing in xampp (windows)

Tags: php, laravel, xampp, pyrocms

I am getting below error after downloading the package:

```
**In MigrateCommand.php line 58:

  Too few arguments to function Illuminate\Database\Console\Migrations\MigrateCommand::__construct(), 1 passed in C:\xampp\htdocs\pyro\vendor\anomaly\streams-platform\src\Database\Migration\MigrationServiceProvider.php on line 88 and exactly 2 expected**
```

Above error is generated when entering the command

> php artisan install

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the Same issue! It looks that composer.lock file and your php version are not compatible.

I deleted the composer.lock file that comes with the repo, and the vendor project, after run composer install and then php artisan install.

I hope it works for you!